# JPA Mapping, parent to children and child to parent with two classes and abstract class

Tags: jpa, abstract, many-to-one

I have have two classes that inherit from an abstract class and have a parent-children relation.

So I use annotation OneToMany and ManyToOne but the parent entity in child class is always null.
Can Someone help me please, I have spend several hours to googling and test many conf without success.

These are code from my classes :

```
public @Table(name="flowentity") @Entity abstract class FlowEntity {

final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FlowEntity.class);

//Globals informations concerning the flow state
private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) Integer flowId = 0;
private String flowName;

private @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
        Set<PeopleEntity> actorSet = new HashSet<>();


//Global parameters for most of flows
//Organizational parameters
private @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="organisationalEntity_Id")
        OrganisationalEntity organisationalEntity;
```

...

```
public @Table(name="ams_newCPEntity") @Entity class NewMultiCPEntity  extends FlowEntity {

private @OneToMany(targetEntity=NewCPEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="parent") 
        Set<NewCPEntity> cpList = new HashSet<NewCPEntity>();

//Constructor
    public NewMultiCPEntity(){
        setFlowName(EnumFlow.N_CP_M.getFlowAcronym());
    }
```

...

```
public @Table(name="ams_newCPEntity") @Entity class NewCPEntity extends FlowEntity {

final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewCPEntity.class);

private boolean formNCPValidated;

private @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="parent_Id", nullable=false)
        NewMultiCPEntity parent;

public NewCPEntity(){
    log.debug("Instanciation of a new CP");
    setFlowName(EnumFlow.N_CP.getFlowAcronym());
}

public @Override OrganisationalEntity getOrganisationalEntity(){
    return parent.getOrganisationalEntity();
}
```

...

If I don't add the @JoinColumn annotation, JPA create an association table but is not able to retrieve the parent whereas the association can be done directly by requesting in database.

Thankyou very much to help.

Regards,

Comment: Why are the two subclasses in the same ams_newCPEntity table?  It might not be related but if subclasses all use the ams_newCPEntity table, you might wamt to add it as a secondary table to the abstract Flow entity rather than in each subclass.  If you do not add the @JoinColumn to the ManyToOne parent mapping, JPA requires the join column to default to "parent_flowId".  If it is using a relation table instead, this indicates a problem with how the JPA provider is  processing your annotations.  Turn on logging and check for warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Chris for your comment, you are right, I forget to change the name of the table. I don't think it was the problem because the inheritance mapping is in one table flowentity with a DTYPE discriminator column.

Finally I resolve my problem by setting parent attributs when adding a new child like this :

```
public @Table @Entity class NewMultiCPEntity  extends FlowEntity {

    private @OneToMany(targetEntity=NewCPEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
            List<NewCPEntity> cpList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructor
        public NewMultiCPEntity(){
            setOrganisationalEntity(new OrganisationalEntity());
            setFlowName(EnumFlow.N_CP_M.getFlowAcronym());
        }

    public List<NewCPEntity> getNCPList(){
        if(cpList == null){
            cpList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if(cpList.isEmpty()){
            addCPEntity(new NewCPEntity());
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(cpList);}

    public boolean removeCPEntity(NewCPEntity entity){
        return cpList.remove(entity);
    }
    public boolean addCPEntity(NewCPEntity entity){
        entity.setParent(this);
        entity.setOrganisationalEntity(this.getOrganisationalEntity());
        return cpList.add(entity);
    }
```

And I remove the override of getOrganizationalEntity in the child :

```
public @Table @Entity class NewCPEntity extends FlowEntity {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewCPEntity.class);


    private @ManyToOne(targetEntity=NewMultiCPEntity.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            NewMultiCPEntity parent;

    public NewCPEntity(){
        log.debug("Instanciation of a new CP");
        setFlowName(EnumFlow.N_CP.getFlowAcronym());
    }

    public NewMultiCPEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(NewMultiCPEntity parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
```

Regards,